# How can i execute one by one statement after delaying some time in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I have a problem in iPhone programing.

In my app i want to execute one by one statement after delaying some time.

Example:

```
Label1.text =@"2";
```

Then after delaying some time i want execute:

```
Label2.text =@"3";
```

Then after delaying some time i want execute:

```
Label2.text =@"8";
```

Then after delaying some time i want execute:

```
Label2.text =@"6";
```

Comment: Sounds like this grouping needs to be repeated with different strings. Need array, loop, and timer. Just a guess.

Comment: @user669397 - Welcome to SO, you should accept an answer if one is solving your problem ....

Answer (score 6):

you can use something like this -

```
[self performSelector:@selector(yourMethod:) withObject:someObjectInstance afterDelay:2.0];
```

Comment: you can press F7 key on the keyboard

Answer (score 2):

```
[self performSelector:@selector(updateText:) withObject:self afterDelay:yourDelay];
```

will help you

Comment: Same answer as Saurabh, but his arrived first.

Comment: @Erik B: No offense. My page did not load so couldn't see his answer. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

You are going to use something called an [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) like this:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(update:) userinfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

What this does call the `update:` method on the current object and send the timer object as a parameter. In this method you can update your label.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach than [`NSTimer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/) is to simply sleep between the calls. However, you don't want to lock up the main thread.

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];
```

Comment: @Inder I really don't understand the purpose of your comment. Did you downvote my answer and wanted to let me know why? If that's the case you should start the comment with "-1" and it should read something like this: "-1 Reason for downvote". Just stating obvious facts about an answer doesn't help anyone.

Comment: Thanks Erik for the suggestion. Yeah I down-voted your answer. From the next time I'll use -1. :D

Comment: @Inder That the code does what it's supposed to is not a reason to downvote. You need to specify why you think it's bad to make the thread sleep.

Comment: @Erik Sleeping the thread means you are stopping every thing(I'm assuming that you have only one thread as most of us have). You app will not be able to handle touch events and if your app is executing some thing it will be suspended. So sleeping a thread is not a solution in any case except where you want your application to do  nothing but just irritating the user.

Comment: @Inder Let me quote myself: "However, you don't want to lock up the main thread." This means that if you are going to use this method, you should make sure to do it in a thread different from the main thread. The main thread is the thread that is responsible for handling touch events and if that thread's asleep, yes, that will irritate the user, but I clearly state that you shouldn't do that. So I still don't think your downvote is justified.

Comment: @Erick Everyone has their own point of thinking and I have just done that. I think sleeping a thread is a bad practice for most of the cases and for this Question too. May be you think that is right. But every one has its own point and so I have.